# Ext JS 4.2.1 deploying

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm new to Ext JS.
I have:

Sencha Cmd 4.0.0.203

Extjs 4.2.1.883

SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3

Ruby193

I read Ext JS documentation at guide page for hello world example here:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started

So I created a folder with *helloext* name in webapp of my Tomcat and put ext-4.2.1.883 contents in *extjs* within it and a *app.js* file beside this folder with this content:

```
Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport');
Ext.application({
name: 'HelloExt',
launch: function() {
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
layout: 'fit',
items: [
{
title: 'Hello Ext',
html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
}
]
});
}
});
```

Finally I created an *index.html* with this content:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Ext</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

So my packaging structure is:

- helloext

  - app.js
  - index.html
  - extjs(folder)

That *extjs* (folder) contains all of ext-4.2.1.883 contents.

When I enter this address `http://localhost:8080/helloext/index.html` in browser address bar, everything is ok.

When executing below commands:

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .
```

I got this messages that seems everything is ok and done!

```
D:\application server\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\helloext>
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3

D:\application server\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\helloext>
sencha build -p app. jsb3 -d .
Loading the Project Name Project
Loaded 0 Packages
Loaded 2 Builds
* Parse all-classes.js with options:
- debug: true
- debugLevel: 1
* Parse app-all.js with options:
- debug: false
- debugLevel: 1
* Compress and obfuscate app-all.js...
Copy resources...
Done building!
D:\application server\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\helloext>
```

First command create a jsb3 file and second command create two file:

```
all-classes.js
and 
app-all.js
```

The document says:

> all-classes.js: This file contains all of your application's classes.
>   It is not minified so is very useful for debugging problems with your
>   built application. In our example this file is empty because our
>   "Hello Ext" application does not contain any classes.
>
> app-all.js: This file is a minimized build of your application plus
>   all of the Ext JS classes required to run it. It is the minified and
>   production-ready version of all-classes.js + app.js.

I checked this file size:
all-classes.js size is 2.39 MB
app-all.js size is aboub 500 KB.

I created index-prod.html file with this content:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Ext</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

and access it using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/helloext/index-prod.html
```

I get nothing but this error with Firefox and Chrome in console???

Firefox:

```
TypeError: Ext.cmd is undefined
TypeError: Ext.EventManager is undefined
```

Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'derive' of undefined 
(anonymous function)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onWindowResize' of undefined app-all.js:4
Ext.define.constructor app-all.js:4
i ext.js:21
(anonymous function) app-all.js:4
Ext.ClassManager.processCreate ext.js:21
Ext.ClassManager.processCreate ext.js:21
(anonymous function) ext.js:21
Ext.apply.onBeforeCreated ext.js:21
Ext.apply.doProcess ext.js:21
Ext.apply.process ext.js:21
Ext.Class.c ext.js:21
Ext.ClassManager.create ext.js:21
Ext.apply.define ext.js:21
(anonymous function)
```

So what is my wrong in deploying?

I appreciate you helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the jsb3 way. This was how things were done with extjs 3.x.

Use the Sencha cmd tool to create a standard app, which will serve as a starting point for your developments. Use the following command :

```
sencha -s [path to sdk] generate app [AppName] [folder]
```

This command must be run in the directory where you want to create your app. Say, you want to create an app called `MyApp` in `C:\htdocs\myapp` (this directory should not exist or should at least be empty), you must run these commands:

```
> C:
> cd htdocs
> sencha -s [path to sdk] generate app MyApp myapp
```

As an alternative, if you want to create several apps, you'd create first a workspace, in which you generate your app in a second step.

Once you created your app, you can run `sencha app build` to create the production files. You will repeat this as many times as you like.

Look at the [doc for Sencha cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command). The best doc is the one at the command line obtained with `sencha help` and `sencha help generate`, etc.

Comment: Thank for your answer in short time. i used it but i get error at the end of command execution.  

>sencha -s "d:\Program Files (x86)\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3" generate app MyApp e:\exttest  
...  [INF] [propertyfile] Updating property file: 
e:\exttest\.sencha\workspace\sencha.cfg  

[INF]  
[INF] copy-framework-to-workspace:  
[INF]  
[INF] generate-workspace:  

[INF]

[INF] -after-generate-workspace:

[ERR] Unable to locate 'framework.dir' property from sencha.cfg

[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework 
directory

[ERR] Non-framework directory

Comment: I think you ran into this problem because you didn't run the command in the web root folder, and because you provided an absolute path for your app folder. I added more precise info in the answer. I hope this helps.